# Jquery need to show error message in the next nearest class, depending on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/y53cd3qd/

Have multiple input forms. And next to each input form has `span` with `class="numeric"`.

```
<input type="text" id="miles_per_gallon" class="numeric" >
<span class="errmsg" style="color:red"></span>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="mileage" >
<span class="errmsg" style="color:red"></span>
<br/>
```

There is no parent div or another element

Want. If user types not numeric, then display error in nearest or closest nex `class="errmsg"`

Tried

```
$(".numeric").keypress(function (e) {

if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
//$(".errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
$(this).siblings(".errmsg").html("hmm");
//alert("Digits only");
return false;
}

});
```

But displays the error message in all `class="errmsg"`. How to get to display only in next closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$(this).next(".errmsg").html("hmm");
```

```js
$(".numeric").keypress(function (e) {
//if the letter is not digit then display error and don`t type anything
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
//display error message
//$(".errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow");
$(this).next(".errmsg").html("hmm");
//alert("Digits only");
return false;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="span_left">Miles per gallon<span class="required">*</span>: </span>
<input style="width:145px;" type="text" name="miles_per_gallon" id="miles_per_gallon" class="numeric" placeholder="Miles per gallon" value="" >
<span class="errmsg" style="color:red"></span>
<br/>

<span class="span_left">Mileage<span class="required">*</span>: </span>
<input style="width:145px;" type="text" name="mileage" id="mileage" value="" placeholder="Mileage" ><span class="errmsg" style="color:red"></span>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just changed as follows,

```
$(this).siblings(".errmsg").html("hmm"); 
to 
$(this).next(".errmsg").html("hmm");
```

Check this out.